# PHP get url of current page

Tags: php, url, location

I want to get url of page where user is located. PHP file's location is site.com/assets/js/superbanner.php and script executes in site.com. I tried to do it with

```
$ref = urlencode((isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]");
```

But it echoing `https%3A%2F%2Fsite.com%2Fwp-content%2Fthemes%2Ftafri-travel%2Fassets%2Fjs%2Fsuperbanner.php`, not `site.com`. Or if I'm echoing it on site.com/blog123 it still echoing `https%3A%2F%2Fsite.com%2Fwp-content%2Fthemes%2Ftafri-travel%2Fassets%2Fjs%2Fsuperbanner.php`. How can I get location where user is, not location of php file?

Comment: If you just want `site.com`, that' just `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`, you don't need everything else.

Comment: Don't use `urlencode()`, that's encoding all the punctuation characters in the URL.

Comment: If the user is linking to your script, the location that they're coming from will be in `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`

Comment: @Barmar no, I need url of current page, not only if I'm on home page. I use urldecode because JSON macros needs encoded url for query

Comment: How is the page using the PHP script? Is it AJAX?

Comment: Yeah, `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` is what I need.  Can you add answer to my question so I can select it as right? Thanks!

Comment: This has to have been answered dozens of times before. I can't find a duplicate, but it's not worth answering again.